# Reading a Binary file in MATLAB with various format specifications

Tags: matlab, binary, formats, reader

I'm currently trying to implement a binary reader in MATLAB with various format spec types as follows:

```
    %FIELD  %Bytes % VALUE RANGE
    ---------------------------
    field1  %4     Basic Character Set(BCS)-A
    field2  %5     BCS-A 
    field3  %2     BCS-N (positive integer 01 to 99)
    field4  %4     BSC-A
    field5  %10    BCS-A
    field6  %14    BCS-N (integer CCYYMMDDhhmmss)
    field7  %80    ECS-A
```

This is just a tiny subset of the file header of a much larger file with a large amount of data (up to 1GB). Point being, there are several different types of format spec types. So far, what I've done is the following to read in the aforementioned header subset:

```
fid = fopen([fnm '.ntf'],'r');
while ftell(fid)~=119
        fseek(fid,0,'bof')
        field1 = fread(fid,4,'int8');
        fseek(fid,4,'bof')
        field2 = fread(fid,5,'char');
        fseek(fid,9,'bof')
        field3 = fread(fid,2,'int8');
        fseek(fid,11,'bof')
        field4 = fread(fid,4,'char');
        fseek(fid,15,'bof')
        field5 = fread(fid,10,'char');
        fseek(fid,25,'bof')
        field6 = fread(fid,14,'int8');
        fseek(fid,39,'bof')
        field7 = fread(fid,80,'char');
 end
fclose(fid);
```

I realize this is very elementary and a very brute way to accomplish what I'm trying to do; not to mention I can't do it for 100's of different fields. I'd like to know if it's possible for me to scan the file in chunks of bytes corresponding to the fields and be able to determine automatically the format type, read it, and store it based on the format; basically, the correct, and more elegant way to do it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the file does not contain any information about the content, parsing has to be done in a similar way. You could skip the `fseek`, you only need it when you want to skip areas in the file. If you have the definition as listed above, i would try to parse this and use it to read the file.

Comment: It is the National Imagery Transmission Format, hence it is actually well defined. The part of interest of the file is actually the images (pixel sets) and its data extensions. All of the information for them are contained within sub headers. The sub headers are similar to what I originally posted where it contains byte size and field type information. So, there will be alot of moving around within the file, and again, there is no set pattern for the various format specs. That's why I wanted to know if there was a more general (an algorithmic way) way to access the data.

Comment: I could do that, but it doesn't dig into  and access all data/image segments.

Comment: So I figured out an approach to read these files, but I got stuck at a few fields I'm unsure of reading.
 
The first field requires the following:
Unsigned binary integer; range of values: 0 to 2^n -1
Here is what I have done which I'm unsure if it is correct:
fld1 = strtrim(char(fread(fi,(2^(nn))-1,'uint8=>char')));

The second field is more confusing. Here is what it requires:
Two IEEE 32-bit Floating Point Numbers
This is what I'm considering:
fld2 = strtrim(char(fread(fi,32,'float32*2=>char')));

Please let me know if my implementations are correct. Thanks.